# Spring Boot with urlencoded data from post man and curl

Tags: rest, post

How to handle the curl/postman request like this in spring boot

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic mytoken" -d '{"searchText":["aaa","bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee","fff"]}' "http://localhost:8080/api/loc
```

Here is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String getWordCountList(@ModelAttribute WordCount searchText) {  
}
```

note that, the WordCount is the model class and it contains two strings. However, When the above curl request is sent, the searchText is always empty.. Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the @RequestMapping value from "/search" to "/api/loc".

Also, try the following template. The one for the REST-ful style:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/loc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getWordCountList(@RequestBody WordCount searchText) {
       return "hello";
    }

}
```

The `@RestController` is a convenience annotation that emphasises the REST-full nature of the controller and adds @ResponseBody semantic `@RequestMapping` methods return types. You could rewrite the example with the `@Controller` annotation instead:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/loc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String getWordCountList(@RequestBody WordCount searchText) {
       return "hello";
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you. it was a typo, and the /api/doc or /search is immaterial, there is something more in it.,the problem still persists.

Comment: Another point here is, the -d and the value given in the curl command, if imported to the postman, the data is going into the x-www-form-urlencoded portion key alone, and not into the value portion